# PlayFramework: Depedencies are not inject using Spring and got NullPointerException

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, playframework, nullpointerexception, java-8

When i try to integrate `Spring-Dependency-Injection` in `Play-framework` with `Java 8`. In controller the dependencies are not injected. I am using spring `stereo-type` annotations. Get
[image: Null-Pointer Exception!]

Follwowing is my code:

Configuration:

```
public class GlobalConfiguration extends GlobalSettings{

private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    super.onStart(app);

    // AnnotationConfigApplicationContext can only be refreshed once, but we do it here even though this method
    // can be called multiple times. The reason for doing during startup is so that the Play configuration is
    // entirely available to this application context.
    applicationContext.scan("com.harmeetsingh13.controllers", "com.harmeetsingh13.service.impl", "com.harmeetsingh13.dao.impl");
    applicationContext.refresh();

    // This will construct the beans and call any construction lifecycle methods e.g. @PostConstruct
    applicationContext.start();
}

@Override
public void onStop(Application app) {
    // This will call any destruction lifecycle methods and then release the beans e.g. @PreDestroy
    applicationContext.close();

    super.onStop(app);
}

@Override
public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> clazz) throws Exception {
    return applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@Component
public class UserController extends Controller{

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public Result findUserById(Integer userId) {
    Optional<User> user = userService.findUserById(userId);
    if(user.isPresent()){

    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
public Optional<User> findUserById(int id) {
    List<User> users = userDao.getAllUsers();
    return users.stream().filter(user -> user.id == id).findFirst();
}
}
```

This is the [link where i found sample application](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-spring-data-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

This is really my stupid mistake. In `play-framework` we always need to put the custom global configuration file in project `app` folder at `root` and `play-framework` always find to search `Global` file name at `app` folder root and load into the memory. In my case, my `GlobalConfiguration` file are not loaded in the memory and default configuration are used by `play-framework`. For `Global-Settings` [click on this link for more information](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal)